# SQL Server 2008 R2: Export data using bcp command and store bcp output into variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

I want to export data using `bcp` command and the output of the `bcp` command should be stored in the variable.

**My try**:

```
DECLARE @Result varchar(max)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL = N'Execute xp_cmdshell ''bcp "SELECT * FROM EMP" QueryOut  "E:\BCP\Result.pec"   -T -t@_@ -c -o "E:\BCP\LogReport.txt"'''

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Result nvarchar(75) OUTPUT', @Result =@Result output

PRINT(@Result)
```

But getting an error in the output:

```
output
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bcp: Unable to open output file E:\BCP\LogReport.txt: No such file or directory
NULL
```

Questions:
1. How to store the above output result into the variable?
2. Given permission to the file and folder too, but still getting this error.

Comment: Where is the drive & directory located? Server side of client side? Note that any directory you pass should be located server side and that the SQL Server account needs access to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
---------------------------------------- 1 -------------------------------------------

DECLARE @Result TABLE
(error_msg VARCHAR(800))

DECLARE 
    @SQL varchar(8000),
    @Result_var VARCHAR(MAX)=''

SET @SQL = N'bcp "SELECT * FROM <MY_DATABASE>.<MY_SCHEMA>.<MY_TABLE>" QueryOut  "E:\BCP\Result.pec"   -T -t@_@ -c -o "E:\BCP\LogReport.txt"'''

-- Insert the output from xp_cmdshell into the table @Result
INSERT INTO @Result (error_msg)
EXEC xp_cmdshell @SQL

-- Merge the rows
SELECT @Result_var = @Result_var + ' ' + ISNULL(error_msg,'') FROM @Result

-- Output in variable
PRINT @Result_var
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

2. For me, your command works, check access to folders and subfolders (for database user), check permissions on the sql server.